# Nested WCF service calls get stuck in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I have a case where I have to send calls to other service methods from a service method. e.g. I call a service method A.Call1() from my smart client application, then after some operations it sends call to B.Call2() and then Call2 method sends call to C.Call3().

When I send few concurrent hits to A.Call1() then all service methods stuck in IIS most of times and times out, anyone suggest a fix or better design.

I'm using simple HttpBinding, 4.6 .Net Framework with IIS 8.5 and using default throttling settings.